# Failed to build active scheme on Xcode Previews

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

i have an issue with Xcode Previews. If I create a new project, previews is working fine but on my active application that's was build with Mojave on SwiftUI isn't working.

I even made a new Project and dragged all files to the new project but something seems to be wrong with some file that this happens.

I always get this error in Previews:

> Failed to build active scheme

See this:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with one of my existing projects... I would not spend too much time on finding it out why this is... after all Xcode 11 and SwiftUI are still in beta... I am sure this will work itself out in a later release...

Comment: @mimo found out the answer. Look at the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg after spending almost 1:30 hours on it I found out that in one fine I had this:

```
@State private var tappedBarIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        print(self.tappedBarIndex)
    }
}
```

Its doesn't work if you have didset

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Xcode Report navigator for more information about the issue.

[image]